# Merge branch to master after Jenkins test successful

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I'm wondering if there is a way to merge a branch to master automatically  after Jenkins test ends up successfully. 
Consider this simple Jenkinsfile in test branch:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                    sh 'echo "HELLO WORLD"'
            }
            post{
                success {
                     //something to add for git merge request
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What code should I write in 'post' or somewhere else, or maybe some plugin is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be in the correct directory to merge. What is if you merge it directly. It's not a good way because you could get some merge errors.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                    sh 'echo "HELLO WORLD"'
            }
            post{
                success {
                     sh 'git merge -X theirs yourbranch'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could ignore some merge errors but then it's possible that your code is not what you expect to that is not a real good solution.

Normally you should run your tests against that branch you want to deploy. So it's better you first merge it into your master branch, resolve all conflicts and then run your tests.